# How to calculate $ \int_{0}^{2K(k)} dn^4(u,k)\;du$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

I want to calculate
$$ \int_{0}^{2K(k)} dn(u,k)^4\;du.$$
Where $dn$ is the Jacobi Elliptical function dnoidal and $k \in (0,1)$ is the modulus. I know from the Fórmula $(314.04)$ of [1] (see page 194) that
$$ \int dn(u,k)^4\;du= \frac{1}{3}[k^2 sn (u) cn (u) dn (u) - k'^2 u + 2(1 + k'^2) E(u)]. $$
where $E$ is the normal elliptic integral of the second kind complete and $E(u)=E(am(u),k)$. From this, how to calculate
$$\int_{0}^{2K(k)} dn(u,k)^4\;du?$$

I am not able to evaluate the expression above at the extremes $0$ and $2K(k)$.

[[1]](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Cr_3CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) P. F. Byrd. M. D. Friedman. Hand Book of Elliptical Integrals for Engineers and Scientis. Springer-Verlag New York Heidelberg Berlim, $1971$.

Comment: The integral equals $2\int_{0}^{K(k)}\operatorname {dn} ^4(u,k)\,du$ and note that $E(K(k)) =E(k) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can the same reasoning be used for $\int_{0}^{4K(k)} cn(u,k)^4\;du$?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh So $\int_{0}^{4K(k)} \text{cn}(u,k)^4\;du=4\cdot \int_{0}^{K(k)} \text{cn}(u,k)^4\;du$. Right?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you! You was help me so much.